# Parse CSS like Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, css, parsing

So for example I could do like this with it :

```
$css = new simple_css();
foreach ($css->find_elements_with_property('margin') as $element) {
  //do my stuff
  if ($something) {
    $elem->spacing = '1px';
  }
}
$processed_css = $css->plaintext();
```

Comment: Something like that would certainly be useful

Answer (score 6):

I searched [phpclasses.org](http://phpclasses.org):

```
 <?php
include("cssparser.php");

$css = new cssparser();
$css->ParseStr("b {font-weight: bold; color: #777777;} b.test{text-decoration: underline;}");
echo $css->Get("b","color");     // returns #777777
echo $css->Get("b.test","color");// returns #777777
echo $css->Get(".test","color"); // returns an empty string
?>
```

Link: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1289-PHP-CSS-parser-class.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm only aware of two projects:

- [PEAR/HTML_CSS](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_CSS/) (abandoned)
- [SirPepe / CSS-Parser](https://github.com/SirPepe/CSS-Parser) (last updated one year ago)

I haven't really used any of them.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is of any use? [sabberworm..](http://www.sabberworm.com/blog/2010/6/10/php-css-parser). available on github https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser, havent used it myself but a college has and mentioned it was useful...

Comment: I use this tool its impressive.

Answer (score 1):

Probably , You can use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same but with LESS (that is the only stable project that I know on the subject) you van achieve the same by using mixins with guards.

Take a look http://lesscss.org/#docs

Hope this helps